# How to avoid running more than one instance of apache tomcat

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

I am using apache-tomcat-7.0.41 on linux environment. In normal cases(when tomcat don't have any app i.e. war file in webapps directory), only when one instance of tomcat can be run. If we try to run more than one instance of tomcat using startup script then process automatically shutdown because of port bind exception.

But when i put my app's war file in webapps directory then startup script instantiate a new tomcat instance each time when startup script is run. For example if i run 2 times startup script then in jps 2 Bootstrap processes are shown.

I am also not able to stop tomcat using shutdown script.

I want to run only one instance of tomcat. If anyone try to run more than one instance it should be automatically shutdown.

Could anyone tell how to handle this situation?

Any suggestion will be really helpful.

Thanks in advance !!

When i am running tomcat then its pid is 8320 and it is using below ports:
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:127.0.0.1:8005       :::*                        LISTEN      8320/java
tcp        0      0 :::8009                     :::*                        LISTEN      8320/java
tcp        0      0 :::22222                    :::*                        LISTEN      8320/java
tcp        0      0 :::8080                     :::*                        LISTEN      8320/java
udp        0      0 :::40161                    :::*                                    8320/java
udp        0      0 ::ffff:192.168.122.108:11007 :::*                                    8320/java

After calling shutdown script Bootstrap process is still shown in jps. And it was using below ports:
udp        0      0 :::40161                    :::*                                    8320/java

22222 and 11007 ports are used by my application and that is shutdown but only one  udp port is not released even after calling shutdown script.

Any idea how to do that?

Comment: how come you are not getting port already in use exception ... by default it uses 8080 always ... what is the port it is using in 1st & 2nd time ? Do you have some setting in the conf/server file saying that if 8080 is in use, use another port?

Comment: Added some more description in above post, please look how it is behaving.

Answer (score 0):

You could solve your problem by starting tomcat as a service / daemon.
The service script will should not allow you to start an already started service.

http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/MMBase-Inst-HOWTO/x321.html

Comment: ya, you can try that option!

Answer (score 0):

This is strange, not expected by Tomcat - until someone changes some config - it should work smooth.

I would suggest instead of going deep into problem, try uninstalling & re-installing the Tomcat. If this doesn't work with current version u r using - try +/-1 version (6.0.x/8.0.0-RC5). Also make sure that there isn't some other software / utility running which is causing this.

Option by Frederic is also worth trying - in case above doesn't bear fruit!

Answer (score -2):

Modify the startup script so it doesn't create a new tomcat process every time.

Comment: What type of modification will be required? Any details?